# Command to set dscp / ToS value on outgoing packets for OS X Mavericks?

Tags: networking, iptables, pf

I want to set a certain DSCP (or ToS) value on all packets sent over port 22. I have an iptables command to do so, but Mavericks only has the equivalent of pfctl and I can't figure out how to translate the command to pf. Can anyone help?

How can I apply this setting, but using pfctl instead of iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j DSCP --set-dscp 0x10
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

man pf.conf

tos  | 
           This rule applies to packets with the specified TOS bits set.  TOS
           may be given as one of lowdelay, throughput, reliability, or as
           either hex or decimal.

```
       For example, the following rules are identical:

             pass all tos lowdelay
             pass all tos 0x10
             pass all tos 16
```

Comment: The OP asked how to set TOS, not filter by it.